# Better way to get tag stats?

Tags: wp-query, statistics, tags

I have over 4000 posts. I am trying to query all the posts and get the count of tags each post has and sum up posts count based on number of tags the post has in dashboard. The posts count shows up properly when post_per_page is less than 2000 but beyond 2000 , the query timesout . It just shows '0' for all.

Code

```
  $args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 4000,
    'post_status'  => 'publish',
  );

  $zerotags = 0;
  $onetag = 0;
  $twotags = 0;
  $morethantwo = 0;
  $sixtags_plus = 0;

  $query = new WP_Query( $args );
  while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

     $posttags = get_the_tags();
     $tag_count = 0;

     foreach($posttags as $tag) {
       $tag_count++;
     }
     if ($tag_count == 0) {
       $zerotags++;
     }
     if ($tag_count == 1) {
       $onetag++;
     }
     if ($tag_count == 2) {
       $twotags++;
     }
     if ($tag_count > 2 && $tag_count < 6) {
       $morethantwo++;
     }
     if ($tag_count >= 6) {
       $sixtags_plus++;
     }

 endwhile;

 echo 'Zero Tags : '.$zerotags.'posts';
 echo 'One Tag : '.$onetag.'posts';
 echo 'Two Tags : '.$twotags.'posts';
 echo 'More than 2 and less than 6 : '.$morethantwo.'posts';
 echo 'More than 6 tags : '.$sixtags_plus.'posts';
```

Is there a better approach to query this so that the timeout doesn't occur?

Comment: Not sure if the problem is the tag count. Query for 4000 posts is already a heavy job with or without tag counting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I addressed [a similar problem](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/184562/1685) not long ago - it's all in the memory:

```
$post_ids = get_posts(
    array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status'  => 'publish',
        'fields' => 'ids', // Just grab IDs instead of pulling 1000's of objects into memory
    )
);

update_object_term_cache( $post_ids, 'post' ); // Cache all the post terms in one query, memory should be ok

foreach ( $post_ids as $post_id ) {
    if ( ! $tags = get_object_term_cache( $post_id, 'post_tag' ) ) {
       $zerotags++;
    } else {
        $tag_count = count( $tags );

        if ( $tag_count === 1 ) {
            $onetag++;
        } elseif ( $tag_count === 2 ) {
            $twotags++;
        } elseif ( $tag_count >= 6 ) {
            $sixtags_plus++;
        }

        if ( $tag_count > 2 && $tag_count < 6 ) {
            $morethantwo++;
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:** Switched `get_the_tags` to `get_object_term_cache` - otherwise we lose all our hard work! (the former hits `get_post`, which will hit the db on every iteration and chuck the post object into memory - props @Pieter Goosen).

**Update 2:** The second argument for `update_object_term_cache` should be the *post* type, not the taxonomy.

Comment: +1: I forget about the `fields` param.

Comment: Trouble is `wp_get_post_terms` bypasses the cache from `update_object_term_cache`, so you save on memory but you get ~4000 database hits.

Comment: Try mine now (switched `get_the_tags` to `get_object_term_cache`).

Comment: Great, that is excellent, now I have learned something as well. Your code comes in at `2 queries in 0.15918 seconds`

Comment: There's still a bit of a memory hit on the term cache (post tag objects are stored for each post, rather than once with a reference) - the ultimate solution would be a custom SQL `COUNT` with a group by.

Comment: Stole a bit from your code :-). Upvoted your answer in return and gave you credit.

Answer (score 5):

You are hiting the db with a 500 mile per hour hurricane, no wonder your query times out.

Here is an idea or two to speed things up

- Add `'fields' => 'ids',` to your `WP_Query` arguments. This will speed up your query dramatically. This will only return the post id's, and this is the only thing that you actually need
- Use `wp_get_post_terms()` to get the post tags. The third parameter takes an array of arguments, one beign `fields` which you can also set to just return `ids` which will also speed up your query as it will also just return tag ID's and not the complete tag object
- Use transients to save your results and flush them when a new post is published, or when a post is deleted, undeleted or updated. Use `transition_post_status`

### EDIT- IDEA TO CODE TRANSITION

Setup the function to delete the tansient if a new post is published, or when a post is deleted or undeleted or updated

In your functions.php

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', function ()
{
        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->query( "DELETE FROM $wpdb->options WHERE `option_name` LIKE ('_transient%_tag_list_%')" );
        $wpdb->query( "DELETE FROM $wpdb->options WHERE `option_name` LIKE ('_transient_timeout%_tag_list_%')" );
});
```

Get the tag count and add it to a transient

```
function get_term_post_count( $taxonomy = 'post_tag', $post_type = 'post' )
{
    if ( false === ( $total_counts = get_transient( 'tag_list_' . md5( $taxonomy . $post_type ) ) ) ) {

        if ( !taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy ) )
            return $total_counts = null;

        $args = [
            'nopaging' => true, //Gets all posts
            'fields' => 'ids'
        ];
        $q = new WP_Query( $args );

        if ( empty( $q->posts ) )
              return $total_counts = null;

        update_object_term_cache( $q->posts, $post_type );

        foreach ( $q->posts as $single_post ) {

            $tags = get_object_term_cache( $single_post, $taxonomy );

            if ( empty( $tags ) ) {
                $no_tags[] = $single_post;
            } else {
                $count = count( $tags );
                if ( $count == 1 ) {
                    $one[] = $single_post;
                 } elseif ( $count == 2 ) {
                     $two[] = $single_post;
                 } elseif ( $count >= 3 && $count <= 6 ) {
                     $more_than_two[] = $single_post;
                 } elseif ( $count > 6 ) {
                      $more_than_six[] = $single_post;
                 }
            }
        }

       $total_counts = [
            'none' => isset( $no_tags ) ? ( (int) count( $no_tags ) ) : 0,
            'one' => isset( $one ) ? ( (int) count( $one ) ) : 0,
            'two' => isset( $two ) ? ( (int) count( $two ) ) : 0,
            'more_than_two' => isset( $more_than_two ) ? ( (int) count( $more_than_two ) ) : 0,
            'more_than_six' => isset( $more_than_six ) ? ( (int) count( $more_than_six) ) : 0
        ];


    set_transient( 'tag_list_' . md5( $taxonomy . $post_type ), $total_counts, 24 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );

    return $total_counts;
}
```

You can use the function as follows in your template

```
$q = get_term_post_count();
if ( $q !== null ) {
     echo 'Zero Tags : '.$q['none'].'posts </br>'; 
     echo 'One Tag : '.$q['one'].'posts </br>';
     echo 'Two Tags : '.$q['two'].'posts </br>';
     echo 'More than 2 and less than 6 : '.$q['more_than_two'].'posts </br>';
     echo 'More than 6 tags : '.$q['more_than_six'].'posts </br>';
}
```

### FEW IMPORTANT NOTES

- The code above is untested and might be buggy
- Requires PHP 5.4 +
- The first parameter is `$taxonomy`. You can pass any taxonomy to the code, the deafault is `post_tag`. The second parameter is `$post_type` which is set to default `post`. You can pass any post type to the parameter
- Modify and abuse as you see fit

### EDIT 1

Fixed a couple of minor bugs, the code is now tested and is working

### EDIT 2 - PERFORMANCE TESTING

---SCRAPPED---

### EDIT 3 thanks to @TheDeadMedic

I have also learned a bit from @TheDeadMedic about [`update_object_term_cache`](http://wpseek.com/function/update_object_term_cache/) and [`get_object_term_cache`](http://wpseek.com/function/get_object_term_cache/) which increases the performance a lot. I have updated ( *stole a bit from @TheDeadMedic, upvoted his answer in return :-)*) my answer with this info. It does hit the memory a bit, but this problem is partly overcome with the use of transients.

The code now gives me

> 2 queries in 0.09766 seconds.

without using transients

Comment: Very nice and detailed answer. I have a question. Why are you not using `delete_transient()`?

Comment: Because the transient set is a dynamic value, the transient name is calculated using the taxonomy name passed, `'tag_list_' . md5( $taxonomy )`. Hope it makes sense :-) @cybmeta

Answer (score 2):

### Frequency table - custom SQL query:

You can try the following custom query for your posts/terms statistics for a given taxonomy, post status and type:

```
/**
 * Frequency data: Count how many posts have a given number of terms, 
 * for a given post type, post status and taxonomy.
 *
 * @param string   $taxonomy    Taxonomy slug
 * @param string   $post_status Post status (draft, publish, ...)
 * @param string   $post_type   Post type (post, page, ...)
 * @return array   Array containing freq. data with 'total' (posts) and 'term' counts
 */

function get_post_terms_stats_wpse_184993( 
    $taxonomy = 'post_tag', 
    $post_status = 'publish', 
    $post_type = 'post' 
){
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = " 
        SELECT COUNT( s.terms_per_post ) as total, s.terms_per_post 
        FROM ( 
            SELECT COUNT( tr.object_id ) terms_per_post, tr.object_id 
            FROM {$wpdb->term_relationships} tr 
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} tt USING( term_taxonomy_id ) 
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} p ON p.ID = tr.object_id  
            WHERE     tt.taxonomy = '%s' 
                  AND p.post_status = '%s' 
                  AND p.post_type = '%s'
            GROUP BY tr.object_id 
         ) as s 
         GROUP by s.terms_per_post
         ORDER BY total DESC";

    return $wpdb->get_results( 
        $wpdb->prepare( $sql, $taxonomy, $post_status, $post_type ), 
        ARRAY_A 
    );
}
```

### Example on an install with ~10k posts:

Here's an example for *category* in *published* *posts*:

```
$stats = get_post_terms_stats_wpse_184993( 
    $taxonomy    = 'category', 
    $post_status = 'publish', 
    $post_type   = 'post' 
);  

print_r( $stats );
```

with the following output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [total] => 8173
            [terms_per_post] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [total] => 948
            [terms_per_post] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [total] => 94
            [terms_per_post] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [total] => 2
            [terms_per_post] => 4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [total] => 1
            [terms_per_post] => 6
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [total] => 1
            [terms_per_post] => 8
        )

)
```

We can output it in a HTML table:

```
foreach( $stats as $row )
{
    $rows .= sprintf( 
        "<tr><td>%d</td><td>%d</td></tr>", 
        $row['total'], 
        $row['terms_per_post'] 
    );
}
printf( "<table><tr><th>#Posts</th><th>#Terms</th></tr>%s</table>", $rows );
```

with the following output:

[image: stats]

So here we can see how many posts have a given number of terms, in order.

Currently the SQL query uses temporary and filesort, so there are definitely opportunities to adjust it. On a 10k posts install this took under 0.2s to run on my small VPS. We could for example remove the post table join to make it faster, but then it would be less flexible.

We can also cache the output, for example with the *transients* API, as mentioned by @Pieter Goosen in his answer.

Comment: I'm quite interested to see how this will perform on 4000 posts. SQL queries is usually a bit faster I would think.

Comment: I think the updated answer will run now, I made it more flexible and dynamic. But I haven't tested it yet on a large scale install ;-) @PieterGoosen

Comment: Ya, unfortunately I also don't have a site of that magnitude. But I defintely like your approach :-)

Comment: There are of course pros/cons to this method, but I like how we get the whole frequency table, without the need to update the PHP code for counting. The answers by you and TheDeadMedic are more WordPress friendly, I think ;-) We could make it faster but less flexible, by removing the post table join. Maybe we could also try some rewrites using `get_col` method that seems to have it's own cache, according to the Codex. @PieterGoosen

Comment: Something to remember if you don't need the kind of flexibility as in my answer. ;-)

Comment: Some useless info ;-), On continuos test, without transients, I get `72 queries in 0.26270` seconds with my method. TheDeadMedic's code gives me `143 queries in 0.66504` seconds, yours came in at a wopping `1 queries in 0.02441 seconds`.

Comment: nice to know, thanks for sharing and testing ;-) @PieterGoosen